# Function (set theory).

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following excercise:

$f : A\rightarrow B$ is a function. $\forall Y\subset B $ we have that $f(f(Y)⁻¹) \subset Y $. Could someone give me an example where the subset is true?.

Kind regards,

Phi.

Comment: Well, it's true for *any* example, so just pick some $f, A, B,$ and $Y$ and check it out. (Also you mean "$f^{-1}(Y)$," not "$f(Y)^{-1}$".)

Comment: I assume you meant $f(f^{-1}(Y))$ and I assume you meant **proper** subset. If so, take $A=\emptyset$ and any nonempty $B$.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a *proper* inclusion. Consider $A = B = \text{real numbers}$, $f(x) = x^{2}$, and $Y = B$.

We have that $f(f^{-1}(Y))$ only contains positive numbers, hence it is properly contained in $Y = B$.

More generally, any non-surjective $f$ will do, as $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq f(A)$ will be properly contained in $B$.

As noted in a comment, you mean $f^{-1}(Y)$.